# How can I figure out why Rails Webpacker is changing my css?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I'm using the rails-webpacker gem in a rails 6.0 project and am including bootstrap along with some other css in a file I don't really have control over.  It's basically just a minified bootstrap along with some additional styles.

Everything looks fine in development, but when I deploy (which calls webpacker:compile or assets:precompile, they both do the same thing) it generates my packs and somewhere in the process breaks some css declarations.  One in particular:

```
background-position: center right calc(.375em + .25rem);
```

is being changed to:

```
background-position: 100% calc(.375em + .25rem);
```

The exact line in bootstrap is:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L2208

I'm assuming that this is being done by some css processor that is being included by @rails/webpacker, but I can't figure out how to debug and isolate which one is causing the change.

Comment: As an additional test, I created an empty Rails 6.0.2.2 project with --webpack, created styles.css as a pack, added bootstrap.min.css and @imported it, updated the webpacker.yml to extract_css, and the ran bin/rails webpacker:compile and the css that was created also had this modification made.  I also tried it with the bootstrap npm package, which didn't change css in the same way...?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```rb
config.optimization.minimize = false
```

In your config to see if that makes it go away?

I believe this is the plugin webpacker is using: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/

A permanent fix would need to edit the webpack config for this plugin.

Comment: I tried setting the config similar to https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md#configuration, in that I added:  "environment.config.set('optimization.minimize', false);" and it didn't make any difference.  Granted, I'm not super familiar with configuring webpacker, let alone rails-webpacker.

Comment: Can you try setting that Rails config setting too just for the heck of it? I think it controls multiple webpacker settings.

Comment: Seems the "optimization" key doesn't exist, I get "ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:97:in `method_missing': undefined method `optimization' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000055e25d2b8ed8> (NoMethodError)".  I poked around under the assets config, but didn't see anything about optimization.